Superforms : updating array of objects
I'm trying to work with schema that looks like this (using zod):
const examSchema = z.object({
    name: z.string().min(4).max(250),
    message: z.string().max(500).optional(),
    maxPoints: z.string(),
    questions: examQuestionSchema.array().min(1),
    shuffleQuestions: z.boolean(),
});

On my svelte frontend i then try to update the questions with a button "add question" that on click does this:
<script lang="ts">
  const { form, errors, constraints, enhance } = superForm<ExamSchema, any, any>(data.form);
</script>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" use:enhance>
    <button
        type="button"
        onclick={() => {
            const newQuestion: ExamSchema['questions'][0] = {
                id: shortUUID.uuid(),
                type: 'abc',
                points: '0',
                question: '',
                answers: [],
            };
            $form.questions = [...$form.questions, newQuestion]
        }}
        class="toolbar-btn"
    >
        <Abc height="16px" width="16px"></Abc>
    </button>
        <button type="submit" class="button-primary save-exam">
            {$i18n.t('teacher_panel.exam_editor.submit')}
        </button>
</form>

Server code:
export const load = async () => {
    const form = await superValidate(zod(examSchema));
    return { form };
};

export const actions = {
    default: async (request) => {
        const form = await superValidate(request, zod(examSchema));
        console.log(form)
        return { form };
    }
} satisfies Actions;

However upon submitting on backend i can log that the data im sending is missing the question despite he UI getting updated properly

Where is the submission code? The given code only updates local state.

Is the enhance the one from Superforms?

Yes, the issue got resolved once i changed the dataType on client to 'json'

Please either post an answer (with more details) if you think this could be useful to other people or delete the question if not.

changing dataType in the client solved the issue:
const { form, errors, constraints, enhance } =
    superForm<ExamSchema, any, any>(data.form, {
        dataType: 'json'
    });

